# "Embarassed" vs. "ashamed"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives, past-participles

Is there any difference between the words *embarrassed* and *ashamed*? If so, could you provide some examples of usage?

Comment: I definitely feel embarrassed while watching Rowan Atkinson or Jim Carrey in their commedies. I don't feel ashamed about that.

Comment: Please read [this blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/writing-good-meaning-questions/) about asking meaning questions.

Comment: See http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/29646/8975 too for an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being *[ashamed](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/ashamed)* typically involves feelings of shame.  Being *[embarrassed](http://www.websters-dictionary-online.net/definitions/embarrassed)* can involve feelings of shame, but need not.  Embarrassment typically involves  feeling uneasy, self-conscious, or discomfited due to wounded pride or confusion.

Also see  [Etymology of “embarrass”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69194) and  [What is the word for the emotion I feel when I see someone being humiliated?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12350) and [Embarrassment for the person talked to](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84182).